# How factor with square root

Tags: factoring, quadratics

I have the following equation that I'm trying to factor, but I'm stuck at the end.

$$\frac{zx^{-4}\sqrt{x}(yz^4)^3}{z^7xy}$$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x^4}\sqrt{x}(yz^4)^3}{z^6xy}$$

$$\frac{(yz^4)^3\frac{1}{x^4}x^{1/2}}{xyz^6}$$

$$\frac{y^3z^{12}x^{-7/2}}{xyz^6}$$

$$\frac{y^2z^{6}x^{-7/2}}{x}$$

I think I can simplify and get rid of the `x` in the denominator but I'm not sure how with that negative fraction `x` exponent in the denominator.

Comment: Use this to simplify further$$\frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:
$$\frac{x^{-7/2}y^2z^6}{x}$$
Remember that $\dfrac{x^a}{x^b}=x^{a-b}$
$$y^2z^6\cdot\frac{x^{-7/2}}{x}$$
$$=y^2z^6x^{-7/2-1}$$
$$=x^{-9/2}y^2z^6$$
$$=\frac{y^2z^6}{x^{9/2}}$$
$$=\frac{y^2z^6}{\sqrt{x^9}}$$
$$=\frac{y^2z^6}{x^4\sqrt{x}}$$
Hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

We use the fact that division by $x$ is the same as multiplication by $x^{-1}$ to combine the remaining appearances of $x$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{y^2x^{6}z^{\frac{-7}{2}}}{x} &=& y^2x^{6}z^{\frac{-7}{2}}x^{-1}\\
                    &=& y^2x^{6}x^{-1}z^{\frac{-7}{2}}\\
                    &=& y^2x^{6-1}z^{\frac{-7}{2}}\\
                    &=& y^2x^{5}z^{\frac{-7}{2}}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

If you have any questions about this let me know.

Comment: Bah...  I just realized I misread the step you are trying to simplify.  The second part of this answer is the part that you need.

Comment: I think you mixed up the x and z in the 4th step of your suggestion to my original problem.  Thus this threw off your answer.

Comment: I did indeed.  Do the steps make sense though?

Comment: I think so, but do you think you can fix the variables so I can make sure I'm doing it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Fixed.  Hope that helps.

Comment: In the first step, the z and x in the numerator are still swapped.

Comment: It should be $\frac{y^2z^{6}x^{\frac{-7}{2}}}{x}$.  This changes the whole equation because of the x in the denominator.

Comment: That's what I put in my fixed version.

Comment: No, your fixed version is $\frac{y^2x^{6}z^{\frac{-7}{2}}}{x}$, not $\frac{y^2z^{6}x^{\frac{-7}{2}}}{x}$.

Comment: Oh.  Got it.  It's hard to read that tiny writing.

Anyways thats close enough that you can use my answer as an example to follow.  I'll leave the correct version for you to solve as an exercise. :)

Comment: Or just follow JChaus approach below.

Comment: I can follow his approach, but is his answer correct? It seems pretty complicated for a simplified answer.

Comment: His answer is in radical form.  The denominator could also be written as $x^{4}\sqrt{x} = x^{4}x^{\frac{1}{2}} = x^{4 + \frac{1}{2}} = x^{\frac{9}{2}}$  Both forms are usually acceptable.

For the record, if you can follow the steps and none of them break any rules, the answer *has no choice but to be correct*.